# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; possible connection string formatting error causes "Could not find installable ISAM file" error?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, connection-string

The macro I'm having problem with is **written in Word VBA Editor and it's lunched from Word.**

It's goal is to link into Excel .xlsm file (treated as a customers database) via Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; connection and, without even opening the file, read whole sheet from that file (sheet name = "data") into a dynamic array which will be searched later.

I have some code written to do this, but it crashes on the connection string, probably because I don't know how to format it - these quotes I mean, I just don't understand how are they placed and why.

Most important thing is that the code is written in Word VBA Editor and it's lunched from Word .docm file.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UseADOSelect()

Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset    'All the results of the query are placed in a record set;

Dim exclApp As Excel.Application
Dim exclWorkbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim cntCntrl As ContentControl
Dim strPESELfromWord As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim intWiersz As Integer
Dim intRemainder As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim arraySize As Integer
Dim strSexDigit As String
Dim strArray() As String
Dim i As Integer


'Set exclApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")   'When no Excel Workbook is open an error 429 will be returned.
'Debug.Print exclApp

Set wordDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
Debug.Print wordDoc

'Set mySheet = exclApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'Debug.Print mySheet.Name

'Set mySheet = exclApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sample")
'Debug.Print mySheet.Name

strPESELfromWord = Trim(Selection.Text)
Debug.Print strPESELfromWord
Word.Application.Visible = True

strSexDigit = Mid(strPESELfromWord, 10, 1)      'Extract 10th digit from PESEL number
Debug.Print strSexDigit
intRemainder = strSexDigit Mod 2
Debug.Print intRemainder

connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm"; & _
                Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"            'something is wrong in the syntax
                                


'strQuery = "SELECT * From [Simple$]"   '[Simple$] is the table name; in this case it's the sheet name;
strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$]"     '[data$]   is the table name; in this case it's the sheet name;
recSet.Open strQuery, connection
Debug.Print " RecordCount = " & recSet.RecordCount
arraySize = recSet.RecordCount

ReDim strArray(1 To arraySize)
For i = 1 To arraySize
   strArray(i) = recSet(i)
Next i


intRow = 2
```

And why is it a `private sub`??  Can I make it just sub?? It wasn't me who wrote this. I downloaded this code from [here](https://youtu.be/L0I24NGrUtc).

I got the connection string from [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2010/).

[image]

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093666/could-not-find-installable-isam-vba) as well, but they discuss different code structure and I cannot transfer the answer into my own example.

```
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
With Conn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strWorkbook & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR=YES"""
.Open
End With
```

Comment: Incidentally I forgot about the "Private Sub" part of your question. It doesn't have to be a Private Sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there is something wrong in the syntax here:

```
connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm"; & _
            
                Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
```

because the string is not correctly formed. At the very least, you need to change it to this:

```
connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm;" & _
            
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
```

(To break that down, if you want your connection string to look like this:

```
Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;";
```

then in VBA you need it to look like this

```
Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";
```

Then, if you split it into two parts like this

```
Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm;
```

Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";

you can imagine that your assignment should look like this:

```
connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm;" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
```

In VBA, when you want to split a statement into 2 lines, you put a space followed by "_" at the end of the first line, which means that you end up with this:

```
connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\customer's_dummy_data.xlsm;" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
```

(I am not sure in this case that you need those extended properties anyway).

Going beyond that, your

```
strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$]"
```

is correct for a worksheet called "data"

and

```
recSet.Open strQuery, connection
```

is fine.

But you can't assume that that query will actually return the number of records in your worksheet. What you see in recSet.RecordCount depends partly on what kind of "cursor" you specify when you open the RecordSet. e.g. When I tested here, recSet.RecordCount was -1. In order to see any data I had to think about testing `recSet.EOF` and using `recSet.MoveNext` to move to the first record in the dataset.

FWIW I hope someone else here has a reliable pattern for Excel access via ADO that you can just plug into your code. I don't. But the other thing you will almost certainly need to deal with when using ADO is that when you try to retrieve field values, you always have to consider the possibility that they may be "null", and that trying to use a null value may throw an error.

Re. The "private sub" thing, not it doesn't have to be a Private Sub.

Answer (score 0):

To finally find a Answer to what is causing my system to Crash.. when it was problem of putting in Quotes around a string in a string.  This was not displayed clearly anywhere else.

I been working on this for hours and all I got was the Msgbox
[Msgbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmvaQ.png)
Just in Case the image does not get through this is what Error states.
"Error
Microsoft Access Database Engine --> Could Not Find installable ISAM."

This is very annoying and puzzling illogical message for a simple syntax error.

of missing " "" ;"";"  Mostly the ;"";" at the end.

Even on Excel 2013 the following Reads and I am
Quoting From the same site mentioned above [This is where you can see there is no ";" on the end string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2013/)https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2013/
Xlsm files
Connect to Excel 2007 (and later) files with the Xlsm file extension. That is the Office Open XML format with macros enabled.

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES";

"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.